# Dynamic remarketing AdWords

Tags: google-ads, remarketing

Dynamic remarketing have this note:

> Dynamic remarketing requires a Google Merchant Center account. Google
>   Merchant Center is available in these countries: Australia, Austria,
>   Belgium, Brazil, Canada, the Czech Republic, Denmark, France, Germany,
>   India, Italy, Japan, Mexico, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Russia,
>   Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, the U.K., and the U.S.

Is some way to use Dynamic remarketing for other country, like Lithuania?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is some way to use Dynamic Remarketing for other country, like
>   Lithuania?

Since Google Merchant Center is not available in Lithuania, [Dynamic remarketing](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3124536?hl=en) is not possible in that country.